# My insert statement does not seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple blog system where I can post entries through a php page to the database in mysql. Whenever I post an entry it doesn't seem to appear on the database and I can't find the issue. Here is my php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = ucfirst($_SESSION['username']);

    if($_POST['submit']) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $subtitle = $_POST['subtitle'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        include_once("connection.php");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO blog (title, subtitle, content) VALUES ('$title', '$subtitle', '$content')";
        mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
        echo "Blog entry posted";
    }
}
else{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

The title, subtitle and content tags are in a html below this and they take values which I intend to send to the database. This is the html:

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
Title:<input type="text" name="title" /><br />
Subtitle: <input type="text" name="subtitle" /><br />
Content:<textarea name="content"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Blog Entry" />
</form>
```

And the connection to the database is:

```
<?php
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","learnlearn");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, try to debug: mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) are are simply ASSUMING the query succeeded. Never do that. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: can you please add 
    `or die(mysqli_error($dbCon))` to `mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql)`

Comment: Check `mysqli_error()` after the query.

Comment: What error do you get? Furthermore the `$query` is not safe for SQL injection.

Comment: I hope you're coding this for fun or furthering your programming skills. If you actually want a blogging platform, use Wordpress.

Comment: Two things. Your code is dependant on whether the session is set, plus `if($_POST['submit'])` you should change that to `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: @Mramaa this is the error I am getting 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle' at line 1'

Comment: You need to escape your data then. ^ `mysqli_real_escape_string()` will fix that. You're entering quotes.

Comment: what @Fred-ii- said use `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$string)`

Comment: ... or use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Comment: OH! I SEE THE PROBLEM IS WITH THE DUMMY TEXT I AM USING

Comment: Thanks guys, Y'all are fracking awesome

Comment: We know lol @user2668069 ;-)

Comment: The real problem is not the data, the problem is that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection ala [Little Bobby Tables  http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/). Skip W3Fools, and go straight to the OWASP project. [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)